# how to integrate qml file into qt-widgets app?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick

I have an qt widgets application. I want to add the switch control to my form.
I added to my form QDeclarative widget and add this line to the code but nothing shown.

```
ui->declarativeView->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.qml"));
```

This is the content of the qml file (I added this file to the resources)
It display in qtcreator under resources/[project_name.qrc]/test.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
Button{
  text:aaaa
}
```

I added the pro file : qt += declarative

What am i doing wrong??

I'm using Qt 5.4.1 QtCreator 3.3.1.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: @techneaz I'm using Qt 5.4.1 QtCreator 3.3.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** `QDeclarativeView` is for older Qt versions. If you are porting an application to Qt 5 then you can refer this [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html).

**2.** For your application you can use the new class in Qt 5.x `QuickView` as shown below.

Create a layout in your ui. Or do it via code. Then add the view to the layout as shown below:

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);
container->setMinimumSize(300, 200);
container->setMaximumSize(300, 200);

view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/test.qml")); // Fetch this url by right clicking on your resource file.
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);
```

**3.** In the `.pro` file just add quick module:

```
+quick
```

**4.** Reference: [Introducing `QWidget::createWindowContainer()`](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/)

**5.** Note: If you have to add a url to a resource file you have to use `:/` refer [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-the-application) for more details.

Comment: setting min/max size does not seem to make sense, can we get something like a size hint from the QML file?