# Get signal from qml into c++ class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I try to figure out how to get signal from QML code and connect it to slot located in C++ class.

I take code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531961/how-to-inegrate-qml-file-into-qt-widgets-app/31533988#31533988) and the control shown on the screen but I can't get the signal.

Here is the relevant code:

test.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Switch{
    id: swt;
    checked:true;
    onCheckedChanged: swt.qmlSignal();
}
```

menu.cpp:

```
Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Menu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);

    container->setMaximumSize(50, 20);

    QObject::connect(container, SIGNAL(qmlSignal()),
                     this, SLOT(receiveFromQml()));

    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/test.qml")); 
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);



}
void Menu::receiveFromQml() 
{
    qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" ;
}
```

I've looked at the examples [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) but I can't make it to work.

This is the error I get :

> qrc:/test.qml:10: TypeError: Property 'qmlSignal' of object Switch_QMLTYPE_4(0x291ac70) is not a function

Comment: remove () after qmlSignal - you are trying to assign properties, not calling function

Comment: @Hcorg  I removed it, Now i dont get the error but still the slot not fired. is the connect statement  correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind C++ property to QML property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591224/how-to-bind-c-property-to-qml-property)

Answer (score 2):

### Simple, mark it as slot

Seems you have a C++ Object and you need to call a slot, so mark the function as a `slot`, then it is exposed automatically. No need for weird connect() in C++.

```
// Seems Switch is a QML Item
Switch{
 id: swt;
 checked:true;
 onCheckedChanged: myCppObj.slot(); // calls the object's slot 
}
```

There are other ways to do it, but it seems this covers your case. If not, please elaborate and we'll refine it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that your example is sufficient and that switch item is the root one as well. This is usually solved like:

```
Switch {
    id: swt

    signal gmlSignal

    checked:true;
    onCheckedChanged: { 
        qmlSignal();
    }
}
```

The Qt [article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html) with details. Also you can have qualifier `swt` when needed so `swt.qmlSignal()` from the other context within that file.

Also, C++ part needs to be fixed as well:

```
Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Menu)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
   QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);

   container->setMaximumSize(50, 20);

   view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/test.qml")); 
   ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);

   QObject::connect((QObject*)view->rootObject(), SIGNAL(qmlSignal()),
                     this, SLOT(receiveFromQml()));
}
```

I did changes by looking at own code that emits similar signal and did not actually try but you need to connect to signal exposed from the `rootObject` of QML `view` and not widget container of it.

Comment: I tried this and get an error :  no matching function for call to 'Menu::connect(QQuickItem*, const char*, Menu* const, const char*)'  , did you missed something?

Comment: I briefly checked with my own code similar to yours and the root object is accessed like (QObject*)view->rootObject() and fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Still have some problems : i get now (in runtime) the folowing error : QObject::connect: No such signal Switch_QMLTYPE_4_QML_6::qmlSignal() in ../bwStimulator/menu.cpp:44   . And when I click on the switch  I get the error :    qrc:/test.qml:13: ReferenceError: qmlSignal is not defined

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to find Qt example with QML passing signal to C++. I can think of why it does not work for you: either Switch is not a root item so we address the signal for C++ wrong or maybe there is some mess in the project so wrong QML file is attached.

Comment: This is the only one qml file i have, i dont think this is a mess in the project. where can i find a simple tutorial to add qt quick control to qt widget project and get from gim signals?

Comment: For instance Qt Creator always offers you those samples right away on the Welcome page or maybe in C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5 or what is location in your OS.

Comment: by the way : i dont understand what is " Switch is not a root item " but i tried to replace that to simple button and get the same result

Comment: Try search 'root' and 'root item' in here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Comment: The answer by Ariel M. is the better approach, as it doesn't require you to mess with QML generated objects on the C++ side.
No need for  a signal, finding an object by name, connect, etc, just simply calling the slot from the QML signal handler

Comment: @KevinKrammer Good to know!

Comment: But mind that calling the slot from QML is implying UI thread which is not necessarily wanted (the slot object can be on the other thread).

Answer (score 0):

You can not create an additional signal in qml, but use the standard properties of objects.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Switch{
    id: swt;
    checked:true;
}
```

C++:

```
class MyHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyHandler( const QObject& object, const QQmlProperty& qmlProperty );
    private slots:
        void handleNotify();
    private:
        const QQmlProperty& m_qmlProperty;
};

MyHandler::MyHandler( const QObject& object, const QQmlProperty& qmlProperty ) :
    QObject(),
    m_qmlProperty( qmlProperty )
{
    static const QMetaMethod metaSlot = this->metaObject()->method( this->metaObject()->indexOfSlot( "handleNotify" ) );
    if( metaSlot.isValid() )
    {
        const QMetaMethod metaQmlPropSignal = qmlProperty.property().notifySignal();
        if( metaQmlPropSignal.isValid() )
            QObject::connect( &object, metaQmlPropSignal, this, metaSlot );
    }
}

MyHandler::handleNotify()
{
    if( m_qmlProperty.isValid() )
    {
        const int qmlPropertyValue = m_qmlProperty.read().value<bool>();
        ...
    }
}
```

using:

```
QQuickView* view = ...;
QObject* quickItem = view->rootObject();
const QQmlProperty* qmlProperty = new QQmlProperty( quickItem, "checked" );
MyHandler* myHandler = new MyHandler( *quickItem, *qmlProperty );
```

Thus, the method `MyHandler::handleNotify` will be called when the property `checked` changes (if it exists for the object `quickItem`).

**P.S.** You can also connect a qml property with a signal.

```
class QmlPropertyWrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        QmlPropertyWrapper( const QObject& object, const QQmlProperty& qmlProperty );
    signals:
        void triggered();
};

QmlPropertyWrapper::QmlPropertyWrapper( const QObject& object, const QQmlProperty& qmlProperty ) :
    QObject()
{
    static const QMetaMethod metaSignal = QMetaMethod::fromSignal( &QmlPropertyWrapper::triggered );
    if( metaSignal.isValid() )
    {
        const QMetaMethod metaQmlPropSignal = qmlProperty.property().notifySignal();
        if( metaQmlPropSignal.isValid() )
            QObject::connect( &object, metaQmlPropSignal, this, metaSignal );
    }
}
```

using

```
QQuickView* view = ...;
QObject* quickItem = view->rootObject();
const QQmlProperty* qmlProperty = new QQmlProperty( quickItem, "checked" );
QmlPropertyWrapper* qmlPropertyWrapper = new QmlPropertyWrapper( *quickItem, *qmlProperty );
QObject::connect( qmlPropertyWrapper, &QmlPropertyWrapper::triggered, [ qmlProperty ]()
{
    if( m_qmlProperty->isValid() )
    {
        const int qmlPropertyValue = m_qmlProperty->read().value<bool>();
        ...
    }
} );
```